# WiX - Show product version in instance productname?

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I can define a product version variable like so :

```
<?define ProductVersion="!(bind.FileVersion.ServiceExeFile)" ?>
```

which I can reference inside string parameters like this :

```
$(var.ProductVersion)
```

..but it is displayed as literal text if I use it in my InstanceTransforms productName parameter.

Can anyone suggest how I might work around this?